# xterm for Reactjs stop scrolling

Tags: xtermjs

using **xterm 3.14.4** for Reactjs. Writing many text chunks to terminal. When a chunk is written, the terminal always scrolls down displaying lastly written lines.
What I need to do is, optionally freeze the terminal scroll. i.e., text chunks will still be written to terminal,  but not automatically scroll down. User is supposed to scroll manually.

I tried to handle this using **onScroll** event like this;

```
myterminal.onScroll(function (e: any) {   
    return 0;
  });
```

or,

```
myterminal.onScroll(function (e: any) {   
    return false;
  });
```

Unfortunately no luck. How can I stop this auto scroll and start it again if needed?

Thanx

Comment: just upgraded to 4.8.1, but couldn't find anything about stopping default scroll

Answer (score 0):

You can try set

```js
term.setOption('disableStdin', false)
```

but you need emulate `Stdin` in your code.